# How to setup mod_python configuration variables?

Tags: python, configuration, mod-python

I'm running a Python server with mod_python, and I've run into some issues with configuration variables.  This is actually two questions rolled into one, because I think they are highly related:

1. I need a way to configure variables that will be available in Python while running.  I currently just have a module that sets some name-value pairs that I import into other modules, but I was reading up on [PythonOption](http://www.modpython.org/live/current/doc-html/dir-other-po.html) recently and was wondering what advantages would be gained from using that instead.
2. I need a way to store state on the server.  I've got access to an API that's limited to running X number of times a day, and once it hits that limit, I need to revert to my (lesser) code.  I'm wondering how I can keep track of how many times I've run the query in a day.

I thought about using a file or the database, but I'm afraid I will slow down requests by having everyone try to access the same file or row at once.  Is there a better way to set this up in mod_python?

Comment: Why mod_python?  Why not mod_wsgi?  Why no framework?  Why not use Django or Pylons or TurboGears?

Comment: Is this going to be one of those "I won't answer your question until you change your entire server setup" deals?

Comment: @Daniel Lew: I'm asking a question so I can understand your situation.  You've chosen some hard-to-use technologies.  The problems you describe are solved (totally solved) in Django, Pylons and TurboGears.  I want to know the reason why you're not using a known, working solution before I comment.

Comment: The answer is, because I didn't know better when I started; this is my first foray into Python servers.  Unfortunately, I'm now stuck with what I've got, at least in the short term.

Comment: @Daniel Lew: Switching may be cheaper than attempting to salvage what you've got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I need a way to configure variables that will be available in Python while running.

   Do what Django does.  Use a simple importable script of Python assignment statements.
2. I need a way to store state on the server.

   Do what Django does.  Use SQLite3.

Also, read [PEP 333](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/) and structure your application components to support WSGI.  This should be a relatively small revision to have the proper WSGI structure to existing code.

When you switch from mod_python to mod_wsgi, you can find numerous components to do these things for you and reduce the amount of code you've written.

Answer (score 1):

1. Using `PythonOption` lets you configure stuff that may need to change from server to server. I wouldn't use it too much, though, because messing with the Apache configuration directives is kind of a pain (plus it requires reloading the server).  You might consider something like using `PythonOption` to specify the name of a settings file that contains the actual configuration variables. (Or you could just look in a standard location for the settings file, like most frameworks do)
2. If you really don't want to consider a file or a database, try `memcached`. It's basically a very simple database (get, set, and clear by key only) that's stored entirely in RAM, so it's very fast.  If all you need to store is a counter variable, though, you could probably just stick it in a Python module as a global variable, unless you're worried about the counter being reset when the module gets reloaded.